# preg_match 401 Access Denied

Tags: php, preg-match, http-status-code-401

I am attempting to use preg_match to check for "401 Access Denied" and if found, echo "failed" else "ok".  I just cant seem to grab the right info so i can output it.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied Set-Cookie: cprelogin=no; 
HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Set-Cookie: 
cpsession=%3aXYBHer1OXxaqzCNVLHNR3ujtmdkZow6PYsnyE8daVUF1lq8fQBiFd7EeHJ99CK93; 
HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Server: cpsrvd/11.34.1.4 Content-type: text/html;
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
preg_match('#^HTTP\/1\.(0|1)\s401#i', $yourheaders, $match);

if(!empty($match) && !is_null($match[1])){
   echo "failed";
}else{
   echo "ok";
}
```

Got:

```
  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Set-Cookie: cprelogin=no;.
  HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Set-Cookie:.
  cpsession=%3aXYBHer1OXxaqzCNVLHNR3ujtmdkZow6PYsnyE8daVUF1lq8fQBiFd7EeHJ99CK93;.
  HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Server: cpsrvd/11.34.1.4 Content-type: text/html;

ok
Array
(
)
```

with 401:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied Set-Cookie: cprelogin=no; 
HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Set-Cookie: 
cpsession=%3aXYBHer1OXxaqzCNVLHNR3ujtmdkZow6PYsnyE8daVUF1lq8fQBiFd7EeHJ99CK93; 
HttpOnly; path=/; port=2082 Server: cpsrvd/11.34.1.4 Content-type: text/html;

failed
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 401
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: Getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" on the preg_match

Comment: edited above solution now it outputs in my case:ok
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 401
    [1] => 1
)

Comment: facepalm, im an idiot haha.  left out a ; at the end of my $headers variable.